# Trigger que acumula o resultado MySQL

Tags: mysql, trigger, sql-update

Considerando as seguintes tabelas:

Jogador(
id;
nome
numero;
) j

equipe_ficticia(
id;
usuarioId;
nome;
pontuacao_ficticia;
) ef

equipe_ficticia_jogador(
id;
equipeFicticiaId;
pilotoId;
) efj

etapa(
id;
local;
ano;
estado;
) e

pontuacao_ficticia_jogador(
id;
jogadorId;
etapaId;
pontuacao_ficticia;
) pfj

Neste cenário, vários jogadores fazem parte de uma equipe. Cada um possui um pontuação adquirida em um determinada etapa.

Gostaria que assim que e.estado fosse atualizado para 'f', fosse também disparado uma Trigger que buscasse todos os jogadores dentro de uma determinada equipe na tabela equipe_ficticia_jogador efj e a partir disso fosse somado a pfj.pontuacao_ficticia de cada um deles acumulando essas pontuações em ef.pontuacao_ficticia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, a partir da resposta do Vitor consegui solucionar a questão.

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER upd_etapa AFTER UPDATE ON etapa
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       DECLARE pfj_equipe_ficticia_id INTEGER;
       -- DECLARE pfj_pontuacao_ficticia_total INTEGER;

       DECLARE pfj_cursor CURSOR FOR
          SELECT efp.equipeId
          FROM equipe_ficticia ef
          INNER JOIN equipe_ficticia_jogador efj ON efj.equipeId = ef.id
          INNER JOIN jogador j ON efj.jogadorId=j.id
          INNER JOIN pontuacao_ficticia_jogador pfj ON j.id=pfj.jogadorId
          WHERE pfj.etapaId = NEW.id GROUP BY ef.id
    FOR UPDATE;
       FOR UPDATE;

       DECLARE pfj_cursor_done INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

       DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET pfj_cursor_done = 1;

       IF NEW.estado = 'f' THEN
          BEGIN
          OPEN pfj_cursor;

          pfj_cursor_loop: LOOP
          FETCH pfj_cursor INTO pfj_equipe_ficticia_id;
          IF pfj_cursor_done = 1 THEN
            LEAVE pfj_cursor_loop;
          END IF;

          SELECT SUM(pfj.pontuacao_ficticia) into @a FROM pontuacao_ficticia_jogador pfj
          INNER JOIN jogador j ON pfj.jogadorId=j.id
          INNER JOIN equipe_ficticia_jogador efj ON j.id=efj.jogadorId
          WHERE pfj.etapaId=NEW.id AND efj.equipeId=pfp_equipe_ficticia_id;


         UPDATE equipe_ficticia          
         SET pontuacao_ficticia = @a WHERE id = pfp_equipe_ficticia_id; 
         END LOOP pfj_cursor_loop;
         CLOSE pfj_cursor;
         END
       END IF;
    END;//
   DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Gabriel, vai ser necessário usar um `CURSOR` no MySQL. É difícil acertar sem testar, mas sua *trigger* seria algo parecido com isso:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER upd_etapa AFTER UPDATE ON etapa
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE pfj_equipe_ficticia_id INTEGER;
    DECLARE pfj_pontuacao_ficticia_total INTEGER;

    DECLARE pfj_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT efj.equipe_ficticia_id, SUM(pfj.pontuacao_ficticia)
        FROM pontuacao_ficticia_jogador pfj
        INNER JOIN equipe_ficticia_jogador efj ON efj.jogador_id = pfj.jogador_id
        WHERE pfj.etapa_id = NEW.id
        FOR UPDATE;

    DECLARE pfj_cursor_done INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET pfj_cursor_done = 1;

    IF NEW.estado = 'f' THEN
    BEGIN
        OPEN pfj_cursor;

        pfj_cursor_loop: LOOP
            FETCH pfj_cursor INTO pfj_equipe_ficticia_id, pfj_pontuacao_ficticia_total;
            IF pfj_cursor_done = 1 THEN
                LEAVE pfj_cursor_loop;
            END IF;

            UPDATE equipe_ficticia SET pontuacao_ficticia = pfj_pontuacao_ficticia_total WHERE id = pfj_equipe_ficticia_id; 
        END LOOP pfj_cursor_loop;
        CLOSE pfj_cursor;
    END IF;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Referência de gatilhos (triggers): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Referência de cursores: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html

Comment: Sua resposta foi de grande valia, e parti dela para encontrar a solução. O único problema nela é que a consulta do cursor possuía apenas um filtro na clausula where, o que fazia com que fossem buscados todos os jogadores que participaram da etapa, somasse os seus pontos e gravasse no primeiro índice da tabela equipe_ficticia.
Além do gp precisava também filtrar a equipe, para assim dividir os pontos pelas equipes de acordo com os jogadores que ela possui. Vou postar aqui a resolução final.

Comment: É difícil acertar na mosca sem testar. Fico feliz que tenha chegado a uma solução.